# Retrieve Number of JMS Message retry

Tags: transactions, jakarta-ee, jms, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I am using JMS Queue, and MDB which listen to it. 
I have a retry mechanism, so when exception is being thrown a rollback to the transaction will occur and the operation will re-executed/

I would like to achieve the Message_retry_number, each time "onMessage" being executed, so I can write the current execution retry number.
I heard I can retrieve it through the Header of the message object, but couldn't find anything in the properties or in the net.

anyone has any clue?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See javax.jms.Message.getIntProperty. Property name is "JMSXDeliveryCount".

Answer (score 1):

The only standard way to do this is be having a look at the JMSXDeliveryCount property. However you should be aware that the JMS specification states that JMS defined properties (those starting with JMSX) are optional - so it depends on your specific provider whether this property is supported, and set in every case.

Answer (score 1):

From oracle tutorial [https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jms-concepts003.htm#BNCEH] section 45.3.7.2 Message Properties:

*The JMS API provides some predefined property names that begin with JMSX. A JMS provider is required to implement only one of these, JMSXDeliveryCount (which specifies the number of times a message has been delivered); the rest are optional. The use of these predefined properties or of user-defined properties in applications is optional.*

the JMSXDeliveryCount implementation is required, and it will contain the information you need.